# How to make colorful round particles in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, vertex-shader, particles

I've been trying to render rounded particles using `THREE.PointsMaterial` and passing canvas texture in `map` parameter. Works fine, but I don't know how to use vertexColors to make every particle has own color.

In short:
This code renders **colorful square particles**:

```js
var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
});
```

And this renders **one-color round particles**:

```js
var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
  map: createCanvasTexture(), // returns texture painted on Canvas
});
```

Is there any way to pass vertexColors to `map`?

Or should I use `vertexShader`+`fragmentShader`?
(Probably good solution when I need to animate position as well).
But how to pass the colors in there?

Comment: Add `color` buffer attribute to your geometry and set `vertexColors: true` of points material. And combine your both options: `new THREE.PointsMaterial( { vertexColors: true, map: createCanvasTexture() } );`

Comment: @prisoner849 when you apply texture in `map` it overwrites the `vertexColors`…

Comment: What colour of the texture? Usually, it has to be white, as the material performs channel-wise multiplication of colous of the texture and a vertex.

Comment: @prisoner849 phew! thanks man! white texture made it work! :) thanks a lot!